# $ionicModal service only shows an empty backdrop

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

I am trying to impliment ionic modals in my Cordova Ionic project and the service when fired only show an empty backdrop:

`// Create the Vibe modal that we will use later
  $ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl('templates/new-vibe.html', {
    scope: $scope
  }).then(function(modal) {
    $scope.modalVibe = modal;
  });`

`// Triggered in the Vibe modal to close it
  $scope.closeVibe = function() {
    $scope.modalVibe.hide();
  };`

`// Open the Vibe modal
  $scope.newVibe = function() {
    $scope.modalVibe.show();
  };`

---

### `templates\new-vibe.html`

`<ion-modal-view>
    <ion-header-bar>
      <h1 class="title">My Modal title</h1>
    </ion-header-bar>
    <ion-content>
      Hello!
    </ion-content>
  </ion-modal-view>`

---

### Button Call

`<button ng-click="newVibe()"   id="button_start"   class="button button-outline button-energized" >
             Continue Vibing.
            </button>`

Comment: Don't know if it's the same issue, but in my case it didn't work because I had a Bootstrap css reference.